# BigQuery - Aggregate rows using standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-merge, nosql-aggregation

Consider this table

```
+------------+----------------+-------------+
|    date    |   region_name  |  population |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2000-02-11 | Lower Normandy |   1.000.000 |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2000-02-11 | Upper Normandy |   1.100.000 |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2020-04-25 | Lower Normandy |   1.800.000 |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2020-04-25 | Upper Normandy |   1.900.000 |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

I would like to aggregate rows for `Lower Normandy` and `Upper Normandy` as `Normandy` and, according to the `date` column, sum the `population`.

The expected result would be:

```
+------------+----------------+-------------+
|    date    |   region_name  |  population |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2000-02-11 |       Normandy |   2.100.000 |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2020-04-25 |       Normandy |   3.700.000 |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

The result of this aggregation would then be used to create a new view.

How can I do it in BigQuery using the standard SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to change the name:

```
select date,
       (case when region_name like '%Normandy' then 'Normandy' else region_name end) as region_name,
       sum(population) as population
from t
group by 1, 2;
```

This matches anything that ends in "Normandy".  Of course, you could use `region_name in ('Upper Normandy', 'Lower Normany')` for more precision (and more typing).

Or, if you only care about these four rows, you can just assign the `region_name`:

```
select date, 'Normandy' as region_name, sum(population) as population
from t
where region_name like '%Normandy'
group by date;
```